# People are connecting through my private network

Tags: docker, docker-compose, minecraft, docker-stack

For some reason with my Minecraft server running within a docker stack, it seems like people are going through a proxy. All IP's are internal (10.255.0.16). I can not seem to find the correct way to word this problem as for where I could do a manual Google Search if anyone could help me on my way that would be awesome!

```
version: '3'

services:
    skyblock:
        image: ashdev/minecraft-spigot:1.12.2
        ports:
        - "25565:25565"
        volumes:
        - ".:/minecraft"
        environment:
            MINECRAFT_EULA: "true"
            DEFAULT_OP: "MattsOnMc"
            MINECRAFT_VERSION: 1.12.2
            JVM_OPTS: "-Xmx1500m -Xms500m"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problems were due to me using the default 'bridge' mode network.

By updating to use a 'host' mode network the IP's started showing correctly

```
skyblock:
    image: ashdev/minecraft-spigot:1.12.2
    ports:
    - target: 25565
      published: 25565
      protocol: tcp
      mode: host
```